# Update SQL value in Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a button like this:

```
<a id="MSN89" class="onButton">
```

[image]

I want to change it state to:

```
<a id="MSN89" class="offButton">
```

[image]

By clicking on the first red button, I want to be able to save the value (MSM89 for example) to my sql database.

By clicking on the second grey button, I want to be able to output the value (MSM89 for example) from my sql database.

I tried to make it like this but it reloads the page all the time, and I have too much data, I can't reload it at every click...

```
UPDATE User
SET cards='MSN89'
WHERE User_Id='3';
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136160/jquery-ajax-sql-live-update-via-php-help), but I do not how to implement it in my code.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

---

I tried this type of code, but for sure this is nit the best way and it not refresh the page...

```
<a id="MSN89" class="onButton">
<script>
$(".onButton").click(function() {
  // sql request
  ...
  UPDATE User SET cards='MSN89' WHERE User_Id='3';
  ...
});
</script>
```

```
<a id="MSN89" class="offButton">
<script>
$(".offButton").click(function() {
  // sql request
  ...
  UPDATE User SET cards='' WHERE User_Id='3';
  ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to make an AJAX request rather than a full page request with each button click. What have you tried?

Comment: so do you want the data(i.e MSN89) to  inserted and shown on your page without loading the page right?

Comment: @saran banerjee: Yes please. Without reloading the page.

Comment: Can you show some code? In order to achieve this you need some javascript (In order to make the ajax call), and some php in order to perform the database operations.

Comment: @George Cummins & Muc: i updated the code.

Comment: Francois I have post the answer I  hope it will help u in solving your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have to use ajax
for the js code you need a jquery library which you can get from anywhere.

js code

```
function FnBookmark(id,mode){

$.ajax({
                    url:'yourdomain.com/bookmark.php',
                    data:{mode:mode,id:id},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){
                          if(mode == "on")
                          {
                              $("#MSN89").attr("class", "offbutton");
                              $("#MSN89").attr("onClick","FnBookmark('MSN89','off')");
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              $("#MSN89").attr("class", "onbutton");
                              $("#MSN89").attr("onClick","FnBookmark('MSN89','on')");

                          }
                    }
      });
```

Php code : In the bookmark.php

```
if($_GET['mode'] == "on")
{
    $id = $_Get['id']; // this has the value MSN89
    $sql = "UPDATE User
        SET cards='$id'
        WHERE User_Id=3";

    //then execute the query


}
if($_GET['mode'] == "off")
{ 
   $sql = "UPDATE User
        SET cards=''
        WHERE User_Id=3";

    //then execute the query


}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
exit;
```

Html page :

for onbutton

```
<a id="MSN89" class="onButton" onclick="FnBookmark('MSN89','on');">
```

for offbutton

```
<a id="MSN89" class="offButton" onclick="FnBookmark('MSN89','off');">
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Saran! I ll take the time to test it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE 'User' SET 'cards' = 'MSN89' WHERE 'user_id' = 3"
```

MSN89 is not a int value so it should be in quotes I believe

general rule of thumb is INT values don't need quotes, strings do